# How to properly "OR" word groups using Twitter's advanced search?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to do an advanced search to get tweets that MUST include one word from the following three word groups: html or css, developer or engineer, home or remote.

I've read the [Twitter's documentation](https://support.twitter.com/articles/71577) and the query I should be using is:

```
html OR css developer OR engineer home OR remote
```

And I also tried:

```
html OR css AND developer OR engineer AND home OR remote
```

https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=html%20OR%20css%20developer%20OR%20engineer%20home%20OR%20remote&src=typd

I'm getting inaccurate results, it's showing tweets that don't have at least one word from each word group:

[image]

Where is the issue? I've contacted Twitter's support but they don't respond to individual reports :/

**ATTENTION: I don't want results from the `Top` tab. The `Top` tab only shows popular tweets. The `Live` tab shows all the tweets ands that's what I want. https://support.twitter.com/articles/131209**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Twitter's Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search):

> Before getting involved, it’s important to know that the Search API is
>   focused on relevance and not completeness. This means that some Tweets
>   and users may be missing from search results. If you want to match for completeness you should consider using a Streaming API instead.

So that's why the search results are "inaccurate". I ended up creating a Node.js script that uses the Streaming API and filters the tweets I want.

Answer (score 0):

Just put quotes around the words.

`"html" OR "css" AND "developer" OR "engineer" AND "home" OR "remote"` seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Nop. Quotes makes no difference in this case. Still missing words. Thanks for trying

Comment: Oh, huh, it only works for the `Top` tab, and it's perfect there.

Comment: Top shows only popular Tweets. Live shows all tweets and that's what I want. https://support.twitter.com/articles/131209

Answer (score 0):

You need to put brackets around the terms you wish to group. For example:

```
html OR css AND developer OR engineer AND home OR remote
```

becomes

```
(html OR css) AND (developer OR engineer) AND (home OR remote)
```

[Example](https://twitter.com/search?q=%20(html%20OR%20css)%20AND%20(developer%20OR%20engineer)%20AND%20(home%20OR%20remote)&src=typd)

Comment: I remember also trying that. Also does not work on the Live tab. Top shows only popular Tweets. Live shows all tweets and that's what I want. https://support.twitter.com/articles/131209 Thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

You need to put brackets around each group. Also "AND" should be replaced with a space. Try this:

```
(html OR css) (developer OR engineer) (home OR remote)
```

Comment: This version of the query also gives inaccurate results. Thanks for trying